# Eclipse is renaming files in my svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have some repositories on a svn server which include an Eclipse project. In those repositories it is put the bin folder because I have some properties files and I couldn't run the program without putting them in that folder.

Now when I checkout the project, import the project in Eclipse and build it the svn entries for the folder bin are messed. For example in the "entries" file before building the project I had "svn://address/project/bin", but after I build the project in that file appeared "svn://address/project/src".

So could someone tell me how to prevent Eclipse messing with my svn files?

Edit: I'm not using a plugin for Eclipse. I got files using Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you set an exclusion on the source folder under project settings -> build path?

Then it shouldn't copy the .svn files from src to bin.

Sorry, can't test right now to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: I had to add to exclusion pattern all paths with folder ".svn".
Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I cant edit or comment pmac72's answer, so here the two exclusion patterns that worked for me in combination:

1. `.svn`
2. `**/.svn/**`

Enter them under Project->Properties->Java Build Path->[Source]->src->Excluded->Exclusion Patterns

Answer (score 0):

If you have SVN integration plugins (like subclipse) installed within your Eclipse, and you move files around inside the package explorer, then they will perform the SVN move operations for you.  Though as far as I know, subclipse doesn't automatically commit after doing something like this.  You probably made a top-level commit and committed all the moves by accident.

Comment: I'm not using a plugin for Eclipse. I got files using Tortoise SVN.

Comment: Ah, I see. You didn't mention this, except in your tag, which I removed, because I didn't see anything in your actual question about tortoiseSVN.  Re-added.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it.